# SQL - Question about Salesforce table - Link Event with Task

Tags: sql, salesforce, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

In **`salesforce_event`**, we have `created_date`, `account_id` and `who_id`. In **`salesforce_task`**, we have `created_date`, `close_date`, `account_id` and `who_id`.

`event` and `task` can be joined on either `account_id` (if available) or `who_id`. So it looks there will need to be 2 left joins.

I want to get the days between **event** `created_date` and **task** `created_date`, if the **task** `close_date` is within the last 30 days when the **event** is created.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? What I have is below and it's running forever and also seems to be incorrect

```
select 
se.id,
min(se.created_date) - min(coalesce(st1.close_date,st.close_date))
from salesforce_event se
left join salesforce_task st on se.who_id = st.who_id and st.close_date  >= se.created_date - 30 and st.close_date <= se.created_date
left join salesforce_task st1 on se.account_id = st1.account_id and  st1.close_date  >= se.created_date - 30 and st1.close_date <= se.created_date group by 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: so account_id is NULL in same cases and if account_id is not not then who_id will be NULL right ? (vice versa)

Comment: @RonakDhoot actually the who_id will never be null -- we just want to use account_id if it's available

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of two left join you can try it like this

```
SELECT 
se.id,
se.created_date - st.close_date
FROM salesforce_event AS se
LEFT JOIN salesforce_task AS st ON (se.account_id = st.account_id OR se.who_id = st.who_id) AND st.close_date >= se.created_date - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have configured the joins will do the following:

For a given record salesforce_event, you will get all salesforce_task records with the same who_id, and then you will get each salesforce_task record for all avialable account_id. So if 1 salesforce_event id is associated with 20 account_ids and 30 who_ids, you will get 600 records. you got nothing that ties account_id to who_id.  Is that what you want? It seems to me a bit nonsensical but I do not know the content. you do.

Comment: If an event can be linked to a task via account_id, then I want to use the min(created_date) of the task by that account_id to get the days between task created_date and event created date. If an event can only be linked to a task via who_id, then I use the min(created_date) of the task by that who_id to get the days.